# ayuda con este programa en pseitn

Tags: pseudocódigo

Una distribuidora desea un programa para almacenar las ventas de los años 2019, 2020 y 2021, las ventas se registran por cuatrimestre es decir que en cada año solo se registraran 3 ventas de Enero hasta Abril (primer cuatrimestre), Mayo hasta Agosto (segundo cuatrimestre) y Septiembre hasta Diciembre (tercer cuatrimestre). 
Realizar un programa que almacene en un array bidimensional dichas ventas, las filas serán los años y las columnas las ventas, Se debe mostrar un menú al usuario con las siguientes opciones:

Agregar una nueva venta. (En esta opción se debe pedir el año (fila) y el cuatrimestre (columna 1, 2 o 3) al que pertenece la venta, si la posición del array ya tenía una venta en esa posición, se debe mostrar un mensaje al usuario indicando si desea reemplazar la venta, si selecciona si la venta se reemplaza sino no se hace nada)

Mostrar las ventas de un año en específico. (En esta opción se debe pedir el año (fila) que se desea visualizar si el usuario ingresa un año inexistente se debe indicar que dicho año no existe en el sistema, si el año no tiene ventas mostrar un mensaje indicando esto y si el año tiene ventas mostrarlas)

Mostrar el promedio de ventas de cada año. (En esta opción se debe mostrar el promedio de los tres años, si hay un año que no tenga ventas se debe indicar al usuario que dicho año está vacío)

Salir.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

nesesitas declarar una matriz la cual puedes llamar ventas y 2 variables una para el año otra para el cuatrimestre ambas de tipo entero ya eque estas seran tus cordenadas para insertar en la matriz(arreglo bidimencional).

y para consultar si se agrega un nuevo elemento o lo actualizas solo preguntas si dentro de la matriz en la posicion selecionada es distinto a nulo, si es asi solo incertas y si no pues preguntas si desea remplazar .

y ára mostrar las ventas de un año pues lo haces con un ciclo en el cual primero buscas el año seleccionado y si no lo encuentra pues le dices que no existe y si lo encuentra haces el ciclo con la fila seleccionada y cada columna en dicha fila y en la otra es lo mismo optienes la suma de todas las columnas de la fila seleccionada la diferencia es que aqui divides por el numero de columnas

Comment: Esta clase de preguntas que son solo enunciandos suelen terminar cerradas porque aca no hacemos ejercicios. Si ayudamos con problemas en particular